# Hector Navigation and Arduino

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, hector-navigation, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings!

I am new to ROS and i am implementing hector_slam and hector_navigation.

So the hector_navigation hector_exploration_controller publishes a cmd_vel message.

In arduino how can i access this data. How do i subscribe to the message and extract the data?

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238843/hector-navigation-and-arduino/) by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2016-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a very simple example of a 2WD robot with a Pi2 on it than can be controlled via ROS some time ago, see here: [simple_2wd_robot](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot).

On the ROS side, it listens to '/cmd_vel' [here](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot/blob/master/simple_arduino_control/src/joystick.cpp#L60). The left and right motor commands are then computed on the ROS side and sent via rosserial_arduino. On the Arduino side, they are received and used [here](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot/blob/master/simple_2wd_control_arduino/firmware/controller.cpp#L26). This is a very simple implementation that runs open loop. For accurate control, you'd probably want encoders on your wheels.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RoSPlebb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27287/rosplebb/) on 2016-08-02**:
Hey @Stefan Kohlbrecher my hector exploration controller is sending cmd_vel values in bursts and the arduino does not read all the values because the cmd_vel values come in so fast. Is there a way to change how the values are transmitted? Is it intended to be sent out in bursts?